# Linking error while building an open source iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, open-source

I am trying to compile an open source iOS app named Partita, the project seems dead for two years and it look like updates to some things broke a thing or two.

here's what I've done so far (I may have forgotten a step)

One of the dependency (audio kit) were compiled with an old swift version, so I took the newest source code and compiled a brand new framework and replaced the old that pod is giving me

added a "try?" before a function that gave me a "function throw but no catch" error

maybe a tweak or two

At some point I had to compile to send on my iPhone, generic or virtual device return more errors saying AudioKit is unavailable, cannot find declarations, ect. but its fine if i compile for a real device

Now I'm stuck with linking error, here they are

```html
Ld /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork normal arm64
    cd "/Users/pierrick/Documents/Documents - MacBook Pro de Pierrick/Programming/Partita/Pods"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -L/Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork -F/Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork -F/Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Chronos-Swift -F/Users/pierrick/Documents/Documents\ -\ MacBook\ Pro\ de\ Pierrick/Programming/Partita/Pods/AudioKit/iOS -filelist /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/TuningFork.framework/TuningFork -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork.swiftmodule -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioKit -framework Chronos -framework AudioKit -framework Chronos -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pierrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Partita-doeawmfadbgytvfskorsvxjyuroj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TuningFork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TuningFork

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      -[AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit addCustomUgen:] in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _createBoosterDSP in AudioKit(AKBooster-7854F601498F0658.o)
      -[AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit addCustomUgen:] in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for AKFrequencyTrackerDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKTesterDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKTesterAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for DSPKernel in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKOutputBuffered in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKDSPBase in AudioKit(AKBooster-7854F601498F0658.o)
      typeinfo for AKParameterRampBase in AudioKit(AKBooster-7854F601498F0658.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for AKDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKSoundpipeKernel in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKBuffered in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      typeinfo for AKBoosterDSP in AudioKit(AKBooster-7854F601498F0658.o)
      typeinfo for AKExponentialParameterRamp in AudioKit(AKBooster-7854F601498F0658.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for AKSoundpipeKernel in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      vtable for AKDSPKernel in AudioKit(AKDSPKernel.o)
      vtable for AKSoundpipeKernel in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      AKFrequencyTrackerDSPKernel::~AKFrequencyTrackerDSPKernel() in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      AKTesterDSPKernel::~AKTesterDSPKernel() in AudioKit(AKTesterAudioUnit.o)
      -[AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit addCustomUgen:] in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      -[AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit .cxx_destruct] in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel::~AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel() in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
      AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel::~AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel() in AudioKit(AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit createParameters] in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      BufferedAudioBus::init(AVAudioFormat*, unsigned int) in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      -[AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit allocateRenderResourcesAndReturnError:] in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      BufferedAudioBus::allocateRenderResources(unsigned int) in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      ___50-[AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit internalRenderBlock]_block_invoke in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      -[AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit .cxx_destruct] in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      AKFrequencyTrackerDSPKernel::~AKFrequencyTrackerDSPKernel() in AudioKit(AKFrequencyTrackerAudioUnit.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The errors seems to come exclusively from AudioKit (the framework I had to recompile) so maybe thats where I have to change a setting or two for it to work, honestly I'm lost here! I just migrated to Mac ecosystem and I don't get much about the structure of projects and Xcode overall

https://github.com/comyar/Partita
here's the code I'm trying to compile, in case its useful

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Remove and add your third party libraries may solve your problem

Comment: You're on the right way. AudioKit has some issues when you download it with CocoaPods. Delete the AudioKit.framework from the Pods project and download the most recent version: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases. Than import the AudioKit.framework in the Partita app and try to run the application.

Comment: @teja_D The third party libraries would be AudioKit? or all of the pods. I updated AudioKit manually and maybe i missed a step when changing the framework file, maybe I had to change some settings in the project, I added it in "linked library and framework" but thats it

Comment: @SDW  Thats actually what I already did, I recompiled AudioKit 4.1 and although I compiled it successfully, maybe i omitted certain settings that should of been done prior to compiling so the framework is working with Partita

Also I did not use pre-compiled framework because of swift version mismatch, figured if I compile everything myself I would have this issue anymore, it worked, but maybe i caused the current issue because I don't know how to properly compile a framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the AudioKit.framework.

Download the latest release: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases

And follow the instructions: https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Frameworks/README.md#using-the-compiled-frameworks-in-your-projects

What you need to do is add `-lstdc++` in the `Other Linker Flags` and the app will run without errors!

[image]

Comment: I just managed to get it working (without -lstdc++) by using a 3.7.1 compiled by myself (as the pre-compiled complain of version mismatch) but if im using the latest AudioKit and do the instructions you provided, I still have the linker errors :(

I'm glad I can start to work on modifying the app to my taste (thats the point of all this) but having an up to date version of AudioKit would of been great. I'll try again later with a fresh project, as I changed many settings during all of my attempts to make it work

Thanks a lot for the help and confirming that you can make it work though!

Comment: Hmmm strange. Well I've just uploaded my project here: https://files.fm/u/tc37uywd, maybe you can take a look at it if you want. Just open the Partita.xcworkspace and run the application. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your project compile and run on my device and on a iPhone simulation (unlike my version with an older AudioKit)

Although, when I tried it on my device, the application run, but doesn't work as intended, my version with older AudioKit worked perfectly, so I'll probably stick with it although your project compile on simulators too. but thats out of the scope of my question anyway. thanks a lot for the help!